# Select all Persons that NOT continuously present in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the table Persons with the following contents:

```
year    name
2015    John
2016    John
2017    John
2015    Mary
2015    Jennifer
2016    Jennifer
2015    Lisa
2016    Lisa
2017    Lisa
```

How can I get all Persons that not continuously present in all the years?

The Answer should be:

```
2015    Mary
2015    Jennifer
2016    Jennifer
```

Comment: What if nobody was present in 2016? List everybody or consider this year irrelevant?

Comment: everybody should present in the year 2015 - 2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would be to aggregate by name and then assert that a given name's distinct count of years does not equal the total distinct number of years in the entire table.

```
SELECT t1.name
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT name
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) < (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT year) FROM yourTable)
) t2
     ON t1.name = t2.name
ORDER BY
    t1.name,
    t1.year;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query,

```
select * from persons p1
where exists
(select name, count(1) from persons p2 where p1.name=p2.name group by name having count(1) <
(select count(distinct year) from persons));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query:

[SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29106/4)

```
select a.name, a.year1 
from name_test a 
inner join
(select name, count(year1) 
 from name_test
group by name 
 having count(year1) < (select count(distinct year1) from name_test))
b on (a.name = b.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest window functions.  Assuming no duplicates per name:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             count(*) over (partition by name) as cnt_name,
             count(distinct year) over () as cnt_years
      from persons p
     ) p
where cnt_name <> cnt_years;
```